# Control.Lens.Plated.transform does not traverse the entire structure when using Data.Data.Lens.uniplate to provide the Plated instance

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I am using `Data.Data.Lens.uniplate` to define the `Plated` instance for the following self-similar type.

```
data Formula a = Atom a
               | Conjunction [Formula a]
               | If Expr Expr (Formula a) (Formula a)
               deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show, Data, Typeable)

instance Plated (Formula a) where
  plate = uniplate
```

When I invoke `Control.Lens.Plated.transform` to traverse an instance of `Formula a` rewriting the leaf nodes `Atom a`, the traversal does not enter the second "else" branch of the `If` construct! All of the `Formula a` in the list inside the `Conjunction` constructor are traversed, but only the first `Formula a` in the `If` constructor is traversed.

I can't see any significant difference between this code and the example in Haddock (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.2/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#t:Plated)

What am I missing here?

Comment: What *exact* code did you run, what did you expect, what did you get instead?

Comment: Seems like it may be related to this bug too, I don't know what's up with it either https://github.com/ekmett/lens/issues/907